# Is using a database wrapper microservice an anti-pattern?

Tags: database, microservices, anti-patterns

Say I have a microservice that wraps a database, in a way that the entire functionality of that service is hiding the details of the database behind a generic (say REST) API, allowing changing the database without affecting the other services.

Is this an anti-pattern? 
What are the pros/cons of this approach?

Comment: This seems like a good pattern.  It is called an API and is quite common.

Comment: On the other hand, it adds an additional hop in or become a bottleneck, which might have a performance impact, and a general guideline in microservices is that services should implement business logic and use database for persisting state. In this case, the database is the service itself.

Comment: If you are asking permission to not use an API wrapper because it is an "anti-pattern" I doubt you will get any agreement here.  What you describe is a pattern not an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is an anti-pattern.

As stated in [Building Micro Services 2nd page 03](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/building-microservices-2nd/9781492034018/)

> If you see a microservice that just looks like a thin wrapper around database CRUD operations, that is a sign that you may have weak cohesion and tighter coupling, as logic that should be in that service to manage the data is instead spread elsewhere in your system.

It is also called the 'God-Service' anti-pattern

[God Service Anti-Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q8y5.png) as stated in [Designing Event-Driven Systems page 81](https://www.confluent.io/resources/ebook/designing-event-driven-systems/?utm_medium=sem&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=ch.sem_br.nonbrand_tp.prs_tgt.content-search_mt.xct_rgn.emea_lng.eng_dv.all_con.deds&utm_term=designing%20event%20driven%20systems&creative=&device=c&placement=&gclid=Cj0KCQiAz9ieBhCIARIsACB0oGJpDb6JVs-fd8Tiqw2j1giMRuEEeo-PloIv2a_111n6GdnaP31aXiUaAh1OEALw_wcB)

> Now creating something that looks like a kooky, shared database can lead to a set of issues of its own. The more functionality, data, and users data services have, the more tightly coupled they become and the harder (and more expensive) they are to operate and evolve.

[Encapsulation aka information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) is a well-known software design pattern. You should encapsulate your logic in one service and not expose the whole database.